# Intersection of two continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Suppose that $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb{R}$ is continuous and that $f(0)=f(1)$.
>   Show that there is some $p\in [0,1]$ such that $f(p)=f(p+1/2)$

I drew some graphs and tried to show that $g:[0,1/2]\to\Bbb{R}$ defined by $g(x)=f(x+1/2)$ and $f$ intersect. This is intuitive but how do I formally prove it?

Comment: Define $g(x) = f(x) - f(x+\frac{1}{2})$, then $g(0)g(\frac{1}{2})\le 0$

Comment: And how does that help?

Comment: The expression $g(0)g(1/2) \leq 0$ is a cryptic way of saying either (a) $g(0)$ or $g(1/2)$ equals zero, or (b) one of $g(0)$ and $g(1/2)$ is positive and one negative. In case (a), you're done. Now think about how to analyze case (b).

Comment: So by the intermediate value theorem it takes the value $0$ and we are done, right?